# Including SDL headers on android studio

Tags: android, makefile, sdl

I m new to SDL, i have a problem to compile my project example i have:

```
#include "SDL_config.h" //(in red)
```

if i change it to:

```
#include "../include/SDL_config.h" //(it became green)
```

Also i have multiple Anroid.mk files like below, Is there some thing missing in Android.mk files to avoid rewriting all the project headers?

**src\Anroid.mk :**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_PATH)
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/android/Android.include
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/burn/Android.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/burner/Android.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/cpu/Android.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/dep/libs/lib7z/Android.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/dep/libs/libpng/Android.mk

LOCAL_MODULE := arcade
LOCAL_ARM_MODE   := arm

ANDROID_OBJS := android/android.cpp android/android_main.cpp android/android_run.cpp \
        android/android_softfx.cpp android/android_sdlfx.cpp \
        android/android_input.cpp android/android_snd.cpp \
        android/android_stated.cpp

INTF_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/intf
INTF_OBJS := $(wildcard $(INTF_DIR)/*.cpp)

INTF_AUDIO_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/intf/audio
INTF_AUDIO_OBJS := $(wildcard $(INTF_AUDIO_DIR)/*.cpp)

INTF_AUDIO_SDL_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/intf/audio/sdl
INTF_AUDIO_SDL_OBJS := $(wildcard $(INTF_AUDIO_SDL_DIR)/*.cpp)

INTF_INPUT_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/intf/input
INTF_INPUT_OBJS := $(wildcard $(INTF_INPUT_DIR)/*.cpp)

INTF_INPUT_SDL_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/intf/input/sdl
INTF_INPUT_SDL_OBJS := $(wildcard $(INTF_INPUT_SDL_DIR)/*.cpp)

INTF_VIDEO_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/intf/video
INTF_VIDEO_OBJS := $(wildcard $(INTF_VIDEO_DIR)/*.cpp)

INTF_VIDEO_SDL_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/intf/video/sdl
INTF_VIDEO_SDL_OBJS := $(wildcard $(INTF_VIDEO_SDL_DIR)/*.cpp)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ANDROID_OBJS) \
        $(LIB7Z) $(LIBPNG) $(BURN) $(BURNER) $(CPU) \
        $(subst jni/src/,,$(INTF_OBJS)) \
        $(subst jni/src/,,$(INTF_AUDIO_OBJS)) \
        $(subst jni/src/,,$(INTF_AUDIO_SDL_OBJS)) \
        $(subst jni/src/,,$(INTF_INPUT_OBJS)) \
        $(subst jni/src/,,$(INTF_INPUT_SDL_OBJS)) \
        $(subst jni/src/,,$(INTF_VIDEO_OBJS)) \
        $(subst jni/src/,,$(INTF_VIDEO_SDL_OBJS))

#$(warning $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(filter-out intf/input/sdl/inp_sdl.cpp, $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(filter-out intf/video/vid_softfx.cpp, $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(filter-out intf/video/sdl/vid_sdlopengl.cpp, $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(filter-out intf/video/sdl/vid_sdlfx.cpp, $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(filter-out intf/audio/sdl/aud_sdl.cpp, $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(filter-out intf/audio/aud_interface.cpp, $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(filter-out burner/sdl/main.cpp, $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(filter-out burner/sdl/run.cpp, $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(filter-out burner/sdl/stated.cpp, $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(filter-out burn/drv/pgm/pgm_sprite_create.cpp, $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(filter-out cpu/mips3_intf.cpp, $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := minizip
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SDL
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -llog -lz

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**SDL\Anroid.mk :**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

###########################
#
# SDL shared library
#
###########################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := SDL
LOCAL_ARM_MODE   := arm

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -D GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -DHAVE_STDIO_H
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-a8 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3 -O3 -Os
endif

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,, \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/audio/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/audio/android/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/audio/dummy/*.c) \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/atomic/SDL_atomic.c \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/atomic/SDL_spinlock.c.arm \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/core/android/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/cpuinfo/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/events/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/file/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/haptic/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/haptic/dummy/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/joystick/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/joystick/android/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/loadso/dlopen/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/power/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/render/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/render/*/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/stdlib/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/thread/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/thread/pthread/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/timer/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/timer/unix/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/video/*.c) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/video/android/*.c))

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```